# nodejs, socket, https - Socket makes no connection but only disconnects

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, https, socket.io

I've been through A LOT of issues in here about this topic but so far no answers has been the solution for my problem.

My setup is an AWS EC2 server with apache installed. I've installed node.js in the `/node` folder containing a server-file called `server.js` and in the root folder I have my client-file `index.php`. I have Let´s Encrypt SSL-certificates for my domain and therefore I need everything to run over https. I have opened up the port 3000 for all traffic en AWS.

**Server.js**

```
const app = require('express')();
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem")
};

const http = require('https').Server(options, app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on 3000');
});
```

**index.php**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Socket Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="events"></ul>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        const events = document.getElementById('events');

        const newItem = (content) => {
            const item = document.createElement('li');
            item.innerText = content;
            return item;
        };

        const socket = io('https://example.com:3000', {transports: ['websocket', 'polling']});
        
        console.log(socket);
    
        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log("did connect");
            events.appendChild(newItem('connect'));
        });
        
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log("did disconnect");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*The problem*

When I start my node server everything seems right. Executing `node server.js` returns `listening on 3000` as supposed. When I go to index.php it never returns `did connect` BUT when I then exit the server node I get the `did disconnect` message in the browser console.

Also the server never returns anything else but `listening on 3000`.

Please help me :-)

Comment: any errors in console network tab?, there was a recent semvar major update to v3.0.0, if the server is using v3 a v2.x.x client wont be able to connect

Comment: try changing to `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@3.0.0/dist/socket.io.min.js` or use the server's client `https://example.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js`

Comment: Changing the script to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@3.0.0/dist/socket.io.min.js fixed everything! Wow.. that took me two days of debugging. Thank you very much! If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it as the solution. :-)

Comment: np, happened to me too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the recent update to v3.0.0, version 2.x.x clients are not compatible so won't be able to connect.

The fix is to make sure both client and server are using the same versions, or use the server served version `/socket.io/socket.io.js` (which is not always possible, webpack etc)

Related issue on github: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1390

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution for me :-)